# Can I avoid duplicating my service definition for blue-green deployment?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was working on a simple approach for blue-green deployment of an application backend.
I wrote a docker-compose file for the backend from the beginning and migrated the compose file to support blue-green later.

I don't have a need for docker swarm or anything like that.
I use blue-green deployment since every frontend version for that project has to go through a review process before being released and is not allowed to be changed in any way after the review. So whatever backend endpoints I wire for a frontend version, are fixed as soon as it goes to review. So I'm alternating the backend endpoints for each release to have a test and a live backend at any time.

My question is: can I simplify those service definitions somehow, since they are very repetitive? Essentially the blue and green service do the very same thing. I could even use the same port for both since my reverse proxy cares about routing the requests.
But I wasn't able to figure out how to start a service twice with different names (blue or green), so I duplicated the backend service.

```
version: '3'

networks:
  nw1:
    external: false
  nw2:
    external: true

services:
  blue:
    entrypoint:
      - npm
      - run
    command:
      - "start-backend"
      - --
      - -s
      - ${CLIENT_SECRET}
      - -c
      - ${CLIENT_ID}
      - -o
      - ${OWNER_ID}
    build: .
    expose:
      - ${BLUE_PORT}
    networks:
      - nw1
      - nw2
    environment:
      - PORT=${BLUE_PORT}
      - CONFIG=live
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  green:
    entrypoint:
      - npm
      - run
    command:
      - "start-backend"
      - --
      - -s
      - ${CLIENT_SECRET}
      - -c
      - ${CLIENT_ID}
      - -o
      - ${OWNER_ID}
    build: .
    expose:
      - ${GREEN_PORT}
    networks:
      - nw1
      - nw2
    environment:
      - PORT=${GREEN_PORT}
      - CONFIG=live
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./myapplication/data/db:/data/db
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
    networks:
      - nw1
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation on your compose file above (since yml is whitespace sensitive).

Comment: @BMitch done, thx for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple different options. The first is that you can create two completely separate stacks, one for blue and the other for green. You'd need to move any common services outside of that into a third common stack, and connect using external networks and/or volumes. Inside the blue/green stack definition, use variables to configure anything unique to that stack, like your port. This would be my recommended solution since it allows you to easily add more services to the mix, and deploy the same stack outside of a blue/green environment with the same compose file.

The second option is to use Yaml's anchor and alias syntax.

```
version: '3'

networks:
  nw1:
    external: false
  nw2:
    external: true

services:
  blue: &service
    entrypoint:
      - npm
      - run
    command:
      - "start-backend"
      - --
      - -s
      - ${CLIENT_SECRET}
      - -c
      - ${CLIENT_ID}
      - -o
      - ${OWNER_ID}
    build: .
    expose:
      - ${BLUE_PORT}
    networks:
      - nw1
      - nw2
    environment:
      - PORT=${BLUE_PORT}
      - CONFIG=live
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  green:
    <<: *service
    expose:
      - ${GREEN_PORT}
    environment:
      - PORT=${GREEN_PORT}
      - CONFIG=live

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./myapplication/data/db:/data/db
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
    networks:
      - nw1
```

One last option is to define the common parts of your service as an [extension field](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields) and then reuse that within the compose file using the same alias and anchor syntax.

```
version: '3.7'

x-service-common: &service-common
  entrypoint:
    - npm
    - run
  command:
    - "start-backend"
    - --
    - -s
    - ${CLIENT_SECRET}
    - -c
    - ${CLIENT_ID}
    - -o
    - ${OWNER_ID}
  build: .
  networks:
    - nw1
    - nw2
  depends_on:
    - mongodb

networks:
  nw1:
    external: false
  nw2:
    external: true

services:
  blue:
    <<: *service-common
    expose:
      - ${BLUE_PORT}
    environment:
      - PORT=${BLUE_PORT}
      - CONFIG=live

  green:
    <<: *service-common
    expose:
      - ${GREEN_PORT}
    environment:
      - PORT=${GREEN_PORT}
      - CONFIG=live

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./myapplication/data/db:/data/db
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
    networks:
      - nw1
```

Comment: Thx a lot for pointing out the two options and giving samples. I'll probably go with your recommendation of pulling out common services into a separate stack on the long run.